# is there a way to point at a specific column in a table through DECLARE in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a searchstring that is a bit dynamic, and i'm trying to work around a large CASE WHEN scenario, but before i resort to doing a CASE WHEN i'm trying my luck here.

I've tried to execute it in string format "exec('code')" where it works, but then i get another issue with getdate() that i wont go into details with.

```
DECLARE @ProductLines nvarchar(50) = 'usr_author'
DECLARE @searchProductlines nvarchar(50) = 'hc'

SELECT TOP 20
    Productid as Produktid,
    usr_Author AS Author,
    Header AS Title,
    usr_Publisher AS Publisher,
    CustomerId AS Customerid, FROM Products
        WHERE 
       (@ProductLines Like '%' + @searchProductlines + '%')
```

I've scraped away all other code that isn't relevant here. What i want to do is declare @ProductLines as the column 'usr_author' so i in the WHERE clause can use @ProductLines as an dynamic column picker in a drop down menu later.

however, this doesnt work. if i write usr_Author instead of @ProductLines, i get the results i need but then it's a static solution, rather than a dynamic solution. what is best practice in this situation?

Comment: The best practice is to first read about "SQL injection," to which your current approach seems rather vulnerable.  You can't just take in parameters from the outside and use them in your query.  Ideally, if you want to allow the user to be able to choose the column used in the `WHERE` clause, then you should make absolute certain that it comes from an approved collection of columns.  For the product lines, you also have to sterilize that input to make sure it does not contain malicious SQL fragments.

Comment: If you want to perform a wildcard search, the wildcards should be stored inside `@searchProductlines` itself. That query will be *very slow* though, as it can't use any indexes. It looks like you have a denormalized table that you can't query efficiently any more. `ProductLines` should be a separate table

Comment: If you *really* need such wildcard searches, create a full-text search index and use full-text search operations like `CONTAINS()` or `FREETEXT()`

Comment: *Why* do you want to pass the column name as a parameter? Where would that parameter come from? It's far easier for client code to use an ORM to generate a query that only uses the columns and criteria that are actually needed

Comment: to sum up why this is what's being practiced here is basically. the parameters we use in our sql doesnt necessarily have anything to do with what we use in the frontend, everything goes through a quite large .NET solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can only replace constant values using parameters.  You cannot replace identifiers -- including column names, table names, and so on.

You can do this dynamically as:

```
DECLARE @col nvarchar(50) = 'usr_author'
DECLARE @search nvarchar(50) = 'hc'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
SELECT TOP 20
    Productid as Produktid,
    usr_Author AS Author,
    Header AS Title,
    usr_Publisher AS Publisher,
    CustomerId AS Customerid
FROM Products
WHERE @col Like ''%'' + @search + ''%''
';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@col', @col);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@search nvarchar(50)',
                   @search=@search;
```

Answer (score 0):

By declaring this string, you're now comparing it as a string, not a column. Try a more dynamic SQL approach:

```
DECLARE @ProductLines nvarchar(50) = 'usr_author'
DECLARE @searchProductlines nvarchar(50) = 'hc'
DECLARE @sql1 nvarchar(500);

select @sql1 = 'SELECT TOP 20 Productid as Produktid, usr_Author AS Author, Header AS Title, usr_Publisher AS Publisher, CustomerId AS Customerid into #temptab1 FROM Products WHERE (' + @ProductLines + 'Like ''%' + @searchProductlines + '%'')'

exec( @sql1 )

select *
from #temptab1
```

Disclaimer: Not injection proof in the slightest, just a concept

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure dbo.uspSearch(
    @searchProductId int = 0, 
    @searchAuthor nvarchar(50) = '',
    @searchHeader nvarchar(50) = '',
    @searchPublisher nvarchar(50) = '',
    @searchCustomerId int = 0
) as
begin
    set nocount on;

    select top 20
        Productid as Produktid,
        usr_Author AS Author,
        Header AS Title,
        usr_Publisher AS Publisher,
        CustomerId AS Customerid
    from Products
    where Productid = case when @searchProductId > 0 then @searchProductId else Productid end
        and usr_Author like case when @searchAuthor <> '' then '%' + @searchAuthor + '%' else usr_Author end
        and Header like case when @searchHeader <> '' then '%' + @searchHeader + '%' else Header end 
        and usr_Publisher like case when @searchPublisher <> '' then '%' + @searchPublisher + '%' else usr_Publisher end 
        and CustomerId = case when @searchCustomerId > 0 then @searchCustomerId else CustomerId end;
end;

go;

declare @searchProductId int = '1' 
declare @searchAuthor nvarchar(50) = 'hc'
declare @searchHeader nvarchar(50) = 'test'
declare @searchPublisher nvarchar(50) = 'test'
declare @searchCustomerId int = '1';

exec dbo.uspSearch @searchProductId, @searchAuthor, @searchHeader, @searchPublisher, @searchCustomerId;
```

Comment: You may want to use OPTION (RECOMPILE) on the SELECT statement to optimise performance

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact, that the whole approach has a certain smell, the best answer will be: *Use dynamically created SQL* (if you really have / want to stick to this). There are answers already...

Just for fun, there is a fully generic approach using XML like here:

I want to use a statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [name]='sysrowsets';
```

...With generically defined parameters

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)='name';
DECLARE @SearchValue VARCHAR(100)='sysrowsets';

SELECT
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects
    FOR XML PATH('o'),TYPE
).query('/*[*[local-name()=sql:variable("@ColumnName") and text()[1]=sql:variable("@SearchValue")]]')
```

The result is the same row as above, but as XML (which can be transformed into a tabular set again).

```
<o>
  <name>sysrowsets</name>
  <object_id>5</object_id>
  <schema_id>4</schema_id>
  <parent_object_id>0</parent_object_id>
  <type>S </type>
  <type_desc>SYSTEM_TABLE</type_desc>
  <create_date>2012-09-02T23:08:12.370</create_date>
  <modify_date>2012-09-02T23:08:15.340</modify_date>
  <is_ms_shipped>1</is_ms_shipped>
  <is_published>0</is_published>
  <is_schema_published>0</is_schema_published>
</o>
```

As mentioned above, this is not the recommended approach, it will be very slow. I just felt the need to say something against the **impossible** statements :-)

### UPDATE: Tabular result and still generic...

You can use something like this, just to articulate a predicate against a unique value (in this case `object_id`)

```
SELECT o.*
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.object_id=
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects
    FOR XML PATH('o'),TYPE
).query('/*[*[local-name()=sql:variable("@ColumnName") 
              and text()[1]=sql:variable("@SearchValue")]]')
.value('(/o/object_id/text())[1]','bigint');
```